# How can I add a reasonable padding to this bar chart?

Tags: pgfplots, margins, bar-chart

I’m trying to add a uniform padding to all sides of this bar chart. In a different answer on tex.SE I have found the following code, however, I wasn’t able to find values for `xmin` and `enlarge x` to achieve what I have in mind.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xbar,
  y=-0.5cm,
  bar width=0.3cm,
  enlarge y limits={abs=0.45cm},
  xmin=0, enlarge x limits={upper,abs=1.25},
  symbolic y coords={a,b,c,d,e,f,
                          tn},
  ytick=data,
  nodes near coords, nodes near coords align=horizontal
  ]
\addplot table[col sep=comma,header=false] {
0.1,a
0.1,b
0.1,c
0.1,d
0.1,e
0.1,f
9.1,tn
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This was the initial situation, the `9.1` is too close to the right border.

[image]

Adding an enlargement and `xmin=0` fixes the padding on the right but somehow it moves the bars to the right:

[image]

When I try to fix this with the `xmin=1` it results in unexpected behavior:

[image]

Additionally, I would like to remove the dashes on the left and right side.

Comment: Try width=\textwidth, height=\textwidth.

Comment: and same enlarge y limits=1.25 as x does looks nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify both `xmin` and `xmax`.Then enlarge both sides (left and right of x) equally (i.e., remove `upper`).

To remove dashes on left and right add this: `ytick style={line width=0.0001pt},` in axis options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xbar,
  y=-0.5cm,
  bar width=0.3cm,
  enlarge y limits={0.15},
  xmin=0,xmax=10, enlarge x limits={0.05},
  symbolic y coords={a,b,c,d,e,f,
                          tn},
  ytick=data,
  ytick style={line width=0.0001pt},
  nodes near coords, nodes near coords align=horizontal
  ]
\addplot table[col sep=comma,header=false] {
0.1,a
0.1,b
0.1,c
0.1,d
0.1,e
0.1,f
9.1,tn
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it does not seem to work, however: https://i.imgur.com/EDgWGEV.png  `Package: pgfplots 2014/08/04 v1.11 Data Visualization (1.11-3-g4c99d7a)` (MacTeX 2014)

Comment: @mcb Do you mean the yticks? I hope padding is OK.

Comment: The padding is perfect, the crucial setting was `xmax` together with `xmin` I was able to omit the enlargement factor altogether. However, the yticks are not affected.

Comment: @mcb Did you add `ytick style={line width=0.0001pt},` as in the code above?

Comment: Yes, this is just copied and pasted from your answer, so I guess it’s an issue with `pgfplots 2014/08/04 v1.11`?

Comment: @mcb Can't be. I too have the same version with miktex. Try `ytick style={draw=white}`